# Signing Electron build for M1 macs causes renderer to crash

Tags: electron, apple-m1, electron-builder, electron-packager, code-signing-certificate

I've been making intel builds of our Electron app with Electron-Builder for a while, signing them, and being able to run them without issue.

I'm now trying to make an M1/arm build, but it turns out that signing that build causes the renderer to crash. Not signing the build doesn't cause the crash. This isn't an issue for the intel build. (consistent whether build machine is intel or arm, and whether notarize is called subsequently or not)

I see the following during app startup (Note specifically the v8 fatal error at the top, which is the main concern here):

```
[...]
<--- Last few GCs --->


<--- JS stacktrace --->

[22739:0331/171516.826773:FATAL:v8_initializer.cc(820)] 
render-process-gone { reason: 'crashed', exitCode: 5 }
[...]
Error sending from webFrameMain:  Error: Render frame was disposed before WebFrameMain could be accessed
    at EventEmitter.n.send (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:169:417)
    at EventEmitter.b.send (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:165:2494)
    at c.<anonymous> (/Users/armelchesnais/Documents/Rave/desktop/dist/mac-arm64/Rave-blue.app/Contents/Resources/app/main.prod.js:2:587569)
    at c.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at c.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at c.doCheckForUpdates (/Users/armelchesnais/Documents/Rave/desktop/dist/mac-arm64/Rave-blue.app/Contents/Resources/app/main.prod.js:2:993643)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at w.retries (/Users/armelchesnais/Documents/Rave/desktop/dist/mac-arm64/Rave-blue.app/Contents/Resources/app/main.prod.js:2:588005)
Error sending from webFrameMain:  Error: Render frame was disposed before WebFrameMain could be accessed
    at EventEmitter.n.send (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:169:417)
    at EventEmitter.b.send (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:165:2494)
    at BrowserWindow.<anonymous> (/Users/armelchesnais/Documents/Rave/desktop/dist/mac-arm64/Rave-blue.app/Contents/Resources/app/main.prod.js:2:632050)
    at BrowserWindow.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at BrowserWindow.emit (node:domain:475:12)
```

I won't be able to distribute the arm/M1 build of the app as a result from this.
I'm at a loss as to how signing would affect a crash of the renderer only on one architecture.

How do I resolve this?

- electron v17.1.2
- electron-builder 23.0.2

Comment: I fear no one is going to be able to help you understand these errors unless this is an actual bug in Electron itself. Your best bet is probably to open up the `main.prod.js` file and seeing if you can figure out what's happening at the lines that throw the errors, and maybe that can give you a clue.

Comment: the key error:
[22739:0331/171516.826773:FATAL:v8_initializer.cc(820)] 
render-process-gone { reason: 'crashed', exitCode: 5 }
happens before the webFrameMain error, which happens when you try to send a message to a webContent that doesn't exist. What I'm trying to figure out is why the renderer process crashes on the v8 level only when signed on an m1
(no crash when not signed on intel/M1 builds, no crash on signed intel build). This would be an electron specific error as far as I can tell, not JS.

Comment: Consider reporting this as a bug on the `electron-builder` issue tracker. It may not be a bug, but I don't think anyone on Stack Overflow is going to have the answer either way.

Comment: I've already reported it there too. Figured I'd ask here too in case someone knew, instead of wasting time waiting to see if the issue tracker would accept it or not before asking here.

Comment: To confirm, this only occurs if you sign on the M1 machine? Or this happens when you run it on the M1 machine, no matter where you sign it? I'm trying to determine if we're possibly experiencing the same issue here.

Comment: Regardless of where I sign it. So M1 build signed on intel = crash. M1 build signed on M1 = crash. Intel build signed/unsigned anywhere = fine. M1 build unsigned = fine. I've also got a boilerplate version of electron to run fine when signed as an m1 build. So I'm suspecting a native dependency may be the cause. (I doubt JS based dependencies would cause issues).

Comment: I feel confident the answer I shared will resolve your issue. If you can help whittle down any unnecessary steps it would be greatly appreciated! I suspect that `entitlementsInherit` may be unnecessary, and that `asarUnpack` might also be unnecessary, but I can't test that due to lack of an M1 machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the exact scenario I was facing. I fixed it by updating my `entitlements.plist` to

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

I was missing `com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit`
More details about it is here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_cs_allow-jit
It is documented in the prerequisites
https://github.com/electron/notarize#prerequisites

Answer (score 3):

I don't know with certainty that we're experiencing the same issue as you, but the following steps fixed an issue like this for our users.

In our case it was caused by native dependencies. The `.node` files of native dependencies are treated as separate executables which are expected to be signed under normal circumstances. The sandboxing that occurs when they're not seems only to occur on machines with the new M1 chips.

I'm not certain that all of these changes are necessary because we don't have a machine with an M1 chip. I'll update this answer as I whittle it down, but that may take a while given our lack of hardware.

**Here's the three changes we've implemented, based on my research:**

1. Ensure your `entitlements.plist` has at minimum the following. Also ensure you replicate the properties of the default `plist` for `electron-notarize` if you use it.

```
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
```

[Source](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/3940#issuecomment-511492360)

2. Specify your entitlements file for both `entitlements` ***and*** `entitlementsInherit` ([See docs](https://www.electron.build/configuration/mac.html))
3. Add the following for [`asarUnpack`](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration.html)

```
asarUnpack: ['**/*.node']
```

Please do let me know if this helped!

Comment: Realized I hadn't commented on this way back when, but I already have entitlements files, and unpacked just about everything in the app (due to unrelated requirements). App is still crashing on M1 build. Note it doesn't crash on Intel builds, which makes me suspect those changes aren't the issue. (and intel builds run on M1s without crashing, they just lose a lot of performance that we'd like to reclaim with an actual M1 build). Will update later if it turns out there's some small detail in this fix I missed, if not, assume it hasn't been.