# electron app gives Code Signature Invalid

Tags: electron, apple-m1, electron-builder

I'm building an electron app. So far everything was good, before I tried to upload my app to Mac App Store.

When building, signing and notarizing my app with apple certificates, everything works perfectly. I'm able to sign as Apple Developer ID.

When I tried to generate the pkg to upload to the Apple Mac Store, the MAS app crash.

I tried different combination of entitlements and provisions, but the latest one is:

package.json

```
"mac": {
      "hardenedRuntime": true,
      "gatekeeperAssess": false,
      "entitlementsInherit": "build/entitlements.mas.inherit.plist",
      "category": "public.app-category.productivity",
      "icon": "build/icon.icns",
      "type": "distribution",
      "target": [
        "mas",
        "dmg"
      ]
    },
    "mas": {
      "entitlements": "build/entitlements.mas.plist",
      "entitlementsInherit": "build/entitlements.mas.inherit.plist",
      "provisioningProfile": "build/embedded.provisionprofile"
    },
```

entitlements.mas.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>xxx.com.company.app</string>
    </array>
    
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

entitlements.mas.inherit.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.inherit</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

About the provisionprofile, is one generated with the Apple Distribution Certificate.

When I run

```
pkgutil --check-signature dist/mas/myapp.app
Package "Company":
   Status: signed by a certificate trusted by macOS
   Certificate Chain:
    1. Apple Distribution: MyCompany Inc (XXXXXXX)
```

The package is upload correctly using Transporter, but It get rejected in Apple Review as the app crash when opening.

The crash report doesn't generate any useful information (ar least for me)

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid))
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: CODESIGNING 1 

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0                                       0x7ff7ffcffa2c 0x7ff7ffcfc000 + 14892


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
Error Formulating Crash Report:
dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed
```

EOF

Comment: Not sure if it's the same issue, but this worked for us after a lot of misery: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71759691/